# How to reference a Class Method using an array variable in PHP7?

Tags: php

I've moved from PHP5 to PHP7.

The following code no longer works.

```
<?php

class sandbox {

    function doit() {
        $method = array('name' => 'testresponse');
        return $this->$method['name']();
    }

    function testresponse(){
        return "Hi!"; 
    }



}

$h = new sandbox();
echo "Hello, " . $h->doit();
```

I'm wondering what is the new syntax for this?

Here are the PHP errors I'm getting

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Array to string conversion
>   Filename: front/sandbox.php
>   Line Number: 20

And

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /var/www/application/controller/sandbox.php:20 Stack trace: #0

Comment: First of all, this piece of code should not work for multiple reasons, I assume it is because you have not shown us the real code. Second, that message makes no sense. Please copy and paste the full message.

Comment: If written correctly your code would work, but we don't know what your code looks like at the moment. https://3v4l.org/0Meed

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
return $this->$method['name']();
```

to this

```
return $this->{$method['name']}();
```